# Change table name Identity with Fluent Api

Tags: entity-framework, identity

In my project, I use Identity. Identity's default is to create tables in the DB with their names. I want  to change these names to my names.

I'm using Fluent Api to configuration tables that created Identity, for example:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "Users"; }
    }
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        HasKey(u => u.ProviderId);
    }
} 


public class UserClaimsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "UserClaims"; }
    }
    public UserClaimsConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        HasKey(u => u.Id);
    }
}
```

In Context, I added configuration above that to DB:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RolesConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserClaimsConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserLoginsConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleConfiguration());            
}
```

After that I did a migration and Update-Database –TargetMigration: RenameTablesInDB.

But I'm catching an error:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.AspNetUserClaims" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue.
When you redefine identity's table name with use fluent api. You have to set some mandatory settings.

It's row in IdentityRole

```
this.HasKey<string>(r => r.Id); // It's row decision
```

Also row in IdentityLoginsConfiguration

```
HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
```

And IdentityUserRole

```
HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
```

All together now.
I will describe all the action.
Follow down..

The first, we have files with configurations our DB.
We use `EntityTypeConfiguration` in our configuration.

`EntityTypeConfiguration` is an important class in Fluent API. `EntityTypeConfiguration` provides you important methods to configure entities and its properties to override various Code-First conventions.

Our Classes with configuration:

```
public class RolesConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "Roles"; }
    }
    public RolesConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        this.HasKey<string>(r => r.Id); // It's row decision
    }
}

public class UserClaimsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "UserClaims"; }
    }
    public UserClaimsConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "Users"; }
    }
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
    }
}
 public class UserLoginsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "UserLogins"; }
    }

    public UserLoginsConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId); // It's row was my decision
    }
}


public class UserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "UserRoles"; }
    }

    public UserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId }); // It's row was my decision
    }
}
```

Also we have to add configuration to DB:

```
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RolesConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserClaimsConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserLoginsConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleConfiguration());
        #endregion

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

***BEFORE I have***

[image]

***After, i added configuration to my DB***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bring down the line   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); under

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{


    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RolesConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserClaimsConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserLoginsConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Comment: Brian Driscoll, write differently in book on EntityFramework. You can see here                                                                                  https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=KX_tAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=base.OnModelCreating&source=bl&ots=oni-c87Zhd&sig=ihx5eUWhERuinOH01lz93eWaqbk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ27KA8NzLAhXp_HIKHVxaD344ChDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=base.OnModelCreating&f=false